# How to get input to vector of class?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class `POINT` which consists of x and y coordinates. And I have a vector of this class. How can I get the coordinates from input? I tried `P.x.push_back(x)` but obviously it doesn't work. I am wondering how I can achieve this?
I want to get something like
{{1, 3}, {5, 2}, {7, 2}} as a vector.

```
class POINT {
public:
    int x, y;
};

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<POINT> P(n);
    int x, y;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> x >> y;
        P.x.push_back(x);
        P.y.push_back(y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using C++11 or later, you can use *initializer list*.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> x >> y;
        P.push_back({x, y});
    }
```

Alternative way is to create a temporary structure and push (copy of) that. This way is available also in C++03.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> x >> y;
        POINT point = {x, y};
        P.push_back(point);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to overload `operator>>` in your `POINT` class:

```
class POINT
{
  public:
    int x, y;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, POINT& p);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, POINT& p)
{
  input >> p.x >> p.y;
  return input;
}
```

Your input loop could look like this:

```
POINT p;
std::vector<POINT> coordinates;
while (cin >> p)
{
    coordinates.push_back(p);
}
```

Comment: Adding `operator>>` to `POINT` would also allow the use of `std::istream_iterator` so you can avoid looping through `cin` manually, eg: `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<POINT>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<POINT>(), std::back_inserter(coordinates));`